# How to get numbers from string in C#?

Tags: c#

```
string str="this image has the width of 200px and height of 100px.";
int width, height;
```

How can I code to get

```
width= 200;
height=100;
```

If width is more than 150, i will reduce the width to 150 and i will calculate the height

```
if(width>150)
{
 height=(height*150)/200;
 width=150;
}
```

And the result string would be..

```
str="this image has the width of 150px and height of 75px.";
```

I know `substring()  indexOf() split()`

I know i can split the string with "width" but I dunno how to find the number of that splitted string.

Comment: Is the string always like that, and only the numbers change?

Comment: For the sake of those who have to also work with your code in the future, please rename those members to `width` and `height`!

Comment: string will change but width and height will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few parts to this. First I would suggest a regular expression to match part of the string and explicitly capture the numeric parts of it.

eg, a possible regular expression could be:

```
width\sof\s(?<width>\d+)px\sand\sheight\sof\s(?<height>\d+)px
```

Which matches "width of XXXpx and height of YYYpx" where XXX is captured as a named group `width` and YYY is captured as a named group `height`.

Here's the code so far:

```
string str="this image has the width of 200px and height of 100px.";
var regex = new Regex(@"width\sof\s(?<width>\d+)px\sand\sheight\sof\s(?<height>\d+)px");
var match = regex.Match(str);
```

Now that `match` has 2 groups named `width` and `height` as previously described. Then you use can use `int.Parse` on the capture groups to get the values as numbers:

```
var width = int.Parse(match.Groups["width"].Value);
var height = int.Parse(match.Groups["height"].Value);
```

The last part, changing the number and re-formulating the string you seem to have a good grasp of, so I havent included that.

Here's a live example to demonstrate all of the above: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=CLPS3633

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
string str = "this image has the width of 200px and height of 100px.";
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(str, @"\D+");
// let's say 100x100 is default, so if TryParse fails you get 100x100
int width = 100;
int height = 100;
if (numbers.Length > 1)
{
    Int32.TryParse(numbers[0], out width);
    Int32.TryParse(numbers[1], out height);
}
```

Comment: Since you're dealing with unsafe input, you should use `Int32.TryParse` rather than `Convert.ToInt32` to catch cases where the value would overflow. Otherwise a string of fifty '9' characters would crash your code.

Comment: That's a little better, though you're not checking that the numbers array contains enough numbers :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regular expression match and save 200 + 100.

```
Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str, "this image has the width of (\d+)px and height of (\d+)px.")
```

Afterwards, look the values up in:

```
match.Groups(0).Value
match.Groups(1).Value
```

For C# it's

```
match.Groups[0].Value;
match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse (string) or int.TryParse (string, out int) are probably the methods you want to use to convert a string to an int.

For example:

```
int width;
if (int.TryParse (widthString, out width) == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("The width is {0}", width);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} could not be converted to an int.", widthString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is always like that it becomes a rather trivial task. You basically just have to split the string with " " as the separator, and get the strings from the resulting array at position 6 and 10. Then just subtract the last 2 characters "px" and TryParse to int. You have it. Or just use some fancy Regex, like others will surely suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex,Matches method

```
 string str = "this image has the width of 200px and height of 100px.";
 var  numbers = Regex.Matches(str,@"\d+");
 int no1, no2;

 if (numbers.Count == 2)
  {
    int.TryParse(numbers[0].Value, out no1);
    int.TryParse(numbers[1].Value, out no2);
 }
```