# get number from string regex

Tags: c#, regex

i want to get on c# all the numbers on the string

for example:

```
sadsad 2 fsdg 4 njnjk 5 njnsdf 9 jytjtj
```

i want to get

those numbers , how can i do this?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get numbers from string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658837/how-to-get-numbers-from-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "sadsad 2 fsdg 4 njnjk 5 njnsdf 9 jytjtj 123 456 78 9";
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,5}" /* up to 5 digits */, RegexOptions.Compiled);

            List<int> numberList = regex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex are documented here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

To test regex this site proved helpfull to me: 
http://regexr.com/

Assuming you want a list with Int32 values it could look like this.

```
        string pattern = "[0-9]";
        string input = "sadsad 2 fsdg 4 njnjk 5 njnsdf 9 jytjtj";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection result = rgx.Matches(input);

        var resultList = new List<Int32>(); 
        foreach (Match match in result)
        {
            resultList.Add(Int32.Parse(match.Value));
        }
```

Comment: that good but if i had number with 2 digits that not work...(you code working only with 1 digit)
how can i get for ex. that number 11?
thanks!